# Getting month of the year and day of the week using number of days passed in a particular year

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have to implement the below requirement :

The data which will be provided are as follows:

```
year   -  for example (1997)
no of days passed - for example (365)
```

Using above data I have to find out that on which date 365 days of the year 1997 passed.
Here the **answer** will be : **1997-31-12 (31st Dec 1997)**.

Is there any shortcut to get this value ?

Comment: check http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use calendar class for this purpose, `YEAR` and `DAY_OF_YEAR` are passed as your parameters:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1997);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 365);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

You can format it to your liking as well:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

**Output:**

> 1997-31-12

Answer (score 1):

Using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
DateTime from = new DateTime(1997, 1, 1, 0, 0); // 1997-01-01T00:00:00
DateTime to = from.plusDays(365);
// then you can print "to", use it...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JodaTime:

String date = new LocalDate(1997, 1, 1).plus(Days.days(365-1)).toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        System.out.println(date);

Answer (score 0):

With [threeten](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten) (jodatime's successor) or Java 8, you can write:

```
LocalDate result = LocalDate.of(1997,1,1).withDayOfYear(365);
```